# Poles and zeros from step reponse?

Tags: transfer-function, poles-zeros, step-response

Is there a numerically robust method for calculating the poles and zeros of a discrete-time causal LTI SISO system given its response to a unit-step input?

In the specific example I'm working on all poles and zeros are real, and I would like to calculate them using the exponents and coefficients of the exponentials in the step response (for which I have numerical values).

Comment: Is your step response from a mathematical model or a real physical measurement? Signal-to-noise ratio is a big factor here.

Comment: The step response parameters are from a table in a published paper and were originally obtained by fitting a physical model to noisy measurements.

Comment: I think this is extremely challenging to be "robust" : consider the response from dominant poles (poles close to the frequency axis (j-omega axis in Laplace, or unit circle in z) vs poles that are much further away. The poles that are much further away decay very rapidly while the dominant poles decay very slowly -- this makes the estimation error huge for the weaker poles. For a more robust approach I like to use the phase of the frequency response from which all pole and zero locations can be more accurately determined.

Comment: @DanBoschen I only have access to the estimated step response parameters. These can be used to calculate the transfer function polynomial coefficients directly but the calculations are numerically unpleasant: i.e. multiplications of very small and very large numbers. I can't help feeling there is probably terrible rounding error.

Comment: I agree but for practical purposes it would be sufficient to model the dominant poles and zeros and ignore the insignificant ones — however you said you want an exact solution which means you need very high numerical precision and noise free data of your step response.